# MSSQL Query in Groups of Rows PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I've been trying to get this query working for far too long now, and I figured it was time to ask for help. I'm currently trying to query a MSSQL database from a PHP script using the PDO connection type. I'm trying to get all contents from the rows between certain values (here it's 100 and 200).  This is the query I'm trying to run.

```
SELECT TOP 100 Id, CreateDate, cast(XmlBody as varchar(max))
as XmlBody, ObjectType, Tag, Name
FROM Table WHERE ObjectType LIKE 'StaffPersonal' AND BETWEEN 100
AND 200
```

I typically use MYSQL, so I'm a little lost on the proper syntax for MSSQL (the LIKE keyword was a brutal lesson). This query is throwing a general syntax error.

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   156 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [156]
>   (severity 15)

I'm not sure what's causing this error, but it's driving me crazy.
Thanks in advance for the help, it is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly and you are trying to get the records 100 to 200 from the bigger recordset. You can use the below statement.

`SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Id ) AS RowNum, Id, CreateDate, cast(XmlBody as varchar(max)) as XmlBody, ObjectType, Tag, Name
          FROM      Table
          WHERE     ObjectType = 'StaffPersonal'
        ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   RowNum >= 100
    AND RowNum < 201
ORDER BY RowNum`

Above query uses a subquery and assigns Row numbers based on the Id field (ordered by Id) then filters the result set for the Row numbers 100 to 200.

You can also use the below where statement if you want to use BETWEEN operator

```
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 100 AND 200
```

Between requires a field before it. In this case you need the ROW_NUMBER() function to give you that. I also changed the LIKE to = to make it more efficient since you were looking for exact match.

To try the simplified version on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf15c/4)

Table and data creation

```
CREATE TABLE supportContacts 
(
 id int  primary key, 
 type varchar(20), 
 details varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO supportContacts
(id, type, details)
VALUES
(1,'Email', 'admin@sqlfiddle.com'),
(2,'Twitter', '@sqlfiddle'),
(3,'Twitter2', '@sqlfiddle'),
(4,'Twitter3', '@sqlfiddle');
```

And select query

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Id ) AS RowNum, Id, type, details
      FROM      supportContacts
      WHERE     type = 'twitter'
    ) AS RowConstrainedResult
--WHERE   RowNum >= 1
--    AND RowNum < 2
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 2 
ORDER BY RowNum
```

Comment: @user3525480
Thank you for your response, and you understood me correctly. I tried this query out and now I'm getting SQL error 207: Invalid column name on RowNum. This is definitely a MSSQL server, so I'm not sure why ROW_NUMBER is not working properly.

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting this error. I tried my query on a simplified version of the query on sqlfiddle and it is working fine are you sure there is no misspellings etc?. I am adding code for testing it on sqlfiddle on my original message

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty sure there are no typos as I can run the query if I leave off the BETWEEN and ROW_NUMBER stuff. I'm going to try mssql_connect instead of PDO and see if it's related to that.

Comment: After looking into this some more, it appears that the query was working, it was really an issue with "simplexml_load_string." I assumed it was the query since it would break in different places, and if I pulled a problem row individually, it ran fine. Sorry for the confusion and thank you so much for your help.